# SOAP Magento Error on Customer.Create

Tags: magento, soap, axis

I am trying to create a customer from the Magja project and the AxisFault i am getting is a 100 "Customer email is required." . I am passing over the correct minimum required params from the 1.7 documentation. Long story my fault code is saying i am not including my email BUT it is clearly there (not putting the sensitive info on SO...so you just have to trust me :) ). Any Ideas?

```
Stack
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.

//soapclient line 208
result = sender.sendReceive(method)  -> method variable

<mag:call xmlns:mag="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-XML="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sessionId>9be685563680f52c1ab5375bec545dfe</sessionId>
    <resourcePath>customer.create</resourcePath>
    <args SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
        <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
            <item xsi:type="SOAP-XML:Map">
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">email</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">MY EMAIL</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">password_hash</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">4cb9c8a8048fd02294477fcb1a41191a</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">group_id</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">store_id</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">lastname</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">LName</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">firstname</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Fname</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">website_id</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</value>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </args>
</mag:call>

//magentosoapclient line 215
throw axisFault (axisfault -> message)
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>100</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Customer email is required</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to trace/log the data on the Magento end of things.  Somehow email's getting lost and/or munged in the process.  The PHP code that's called for a customer creation is at

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php
public function create($customerData)
{
    $customerData = $this->_prepareData($customerData);
    try {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setData($customerData)
            ->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $customer->getId();
}
```

and the specific exception being sent back to your SOAP client is at

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php
protected function _beforeSave(Varien_Object $customer)
{
    parent::_beforeSave($customer);

    if (!$customer->getEmail()) {
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Customer', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer email is required'));
    }
```

There's something about your client call and/or the specific Magento system you're using that makes Magento think there's no customer email set.  A few calls to `Mage::Log` should set you on the right path.

Comment: Hey @jejernig. I am facing the same problem, and I am working on the api end and don't have access to the magento server for debugging. As you have marked this as answered, can you please add some info on what was wrong and how you fixed it?